# Should one root be for the whole aggregate graph or should multiple roots be in the same graph?

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, aggregation, aggregateroot

I'm confused about the structure of the following aggregate in my design.

Should one root be for the whole aggregate graph or should multiple roots be  in the same graph?

My case:

**WorktimeRegulation**

```
Id|    Name            |   NumberOfAvailableRotations|  IsActive 
 1|    General Rule    |          2                  |    true
```

---

**WorkTime**

```
Id|  Name   |   NumberOfHours| NumberOfShortDays |WorkTimeRegulationId 

1 | Winter  |     8          |    1              |    1
2 | Summer  |     6          |    0              |    1
```

---

**WorkTimeActivation**

```
 Id|  StartDate  | EndDate      | IsDeFacto |WorkTimeId    
 1 |  2018-10-1  | 2018-12-30   |    1      |    1
```

---

> Note: I consider (StartDate&EndDate) as DateTimeRange(valueobject)

---

Now Should I consider the `WorktimeRegulation` the root for the whole graph, so it controls both (`WorkTime,WorkTimeActivation`)?

> ```
> WorktimeRegulation(ROOT)
>         |
>         V
>     WorkTime
>         |
>         V
> WorkTimeActivation
> ```

Or Should I have Two aggregates like this:

> ```
> WorktimeRegulation(ROOT)          |        WorkTime(ROOT)  
>         |                         |             |
>         V                         |             V
>     WorkTime                      |      WorkTimeActivation
> ```

So In the second solution I have two roots! But If I consider `WorkTime` as a root It will be available to be used separately from the `WorktimeRegulation` and I don't want this because this will break the integrity of the first aggregate.

---

Or Should I have Two aggregates like this:

> ```
> WorktimeRegulation(ROOT)          |      WorkTimeActivation(ROOT)  
>         |                         |             |
>         V                         |             V
>     WorkTime                      |         WorkTime
> ```

Based on the Comment :

> Could you just explain the business problem this solves and what
>   invariants must be protected instead of the database structure

- Every `WorkTimeRegulation` should have at least one `WorkTime` to be valid. So in the creation of `WorkTimeRegulation` I make sure to enforce this invariant.
- I need to check any conflicts between  activated `WorkTime`s, so after that I enforce specific activation based on the recent activation or `IsDeFacto` enforced by the user

---

1. What behaviors can be performed on WorkTime? So far I can see it can
   be activated.

   **Yes, In addition to updating the `WorkTime`, It can be activated.**
2. In order to validate the activation do you need the entire
   activation history or only the latest event?

   **Not the entire activation history, I could say the most recent single    activation history.**
3. Does the activation rules span multiple WorkTime (e.g. if one is
   active then the other can't be)?

   **Yes Per `WorktimeRegulation` I mean If I have `WorktimeRegulation` contains 3 `WorkTimes` then there's one and only one active `Worktime` for this regulation.**
4. Can the name, numberOfHours, etc of activations be modified?

   **If You meant `IsDeFacto` for `Activation` then yes (Through this attribute the user can enforce specific activation if there was conflict between two activations of the same `WorktimeRegulation`),and because the previous attributes in your question belong to `WorkTime` not `Activation`, the `numberOfHours` can be modified.**
5. Should modifying these details conflict with other business
   operations (e.g. activating a WorkTime?

   **If You meant by `these details` the previous attributes,then the answer is no.**
6. "if there was conflict between two activations of the same
   WorktimeRegulation" Could you expand on what kind of conflicts could
   occur? Shouldn't the system prevent activation conflicts from
   occuring? How does the activation process work exactly?

   **According to the business expert explanation: It might happen a conflict     and the system should not prevent it but it alerts this conflict to the end   user.
   The activation performed like this:
   The user selects a specific `WorkTime` in `WorkTimeRegulation` to     activate, Then the activation popup allowing the user to insert StartDate and   expected EndDate, and when the user clicks activate, It should check for any conflict with the previous activation in the same `WorkTimeRegulation` and alert the user if he wants the priority for the previous activation then He should use `IsDefacto` to enforce one of them in the case of conflicts.
   NOTE: The end user doesn't know exactly the end date for activating worktime in advance, So he inserts expected end date, So the conflict may happen.**
7. what would be the cost of having WorktimeRegulation point to a
   non-existing WorkTime for a short period of time (e.g.
   regulation.activateWorkTime(workTimeId) but then the activated work
   item gets deleted)? Can WorkTime get deleted/archived?

   **`WorktimeRegulation` can't point to a non-existing `WorkTime` the work time can't be deleted or archived if it activated once at least, Just activated and (deactivated when activate other work time in the same regulation)**
8. Can WorkTime be associated to a different Regulation after it's
   creation?

   **No**
9. Are you sure it doesn't matter if for instance, name or
   numberOfHours changes at the same time as someone attempts to
   activate a WorkTime?

   **Now I get your question, The user can't change WorkTime after the first activation.**
10. I'm still not clear as to why conflicting activations could occur.
    Why would you want to allow overlapping activation periods, but then
    use a flag to specific which one to enforce. Seems easy enough to
    prevent overlapping activation periods instead, no? Is it really
    possible from the business perspective that two activation periods
    overlap conceptually? Why do users even enter the startDate and
    endDate manually? Couldn't you just track the dates at which
    activation/deactivation occurs in the system?

    **According to the business expert, The start date of the activation for a  specific WorkTime is a decision taken from the company manager(not planned) to work with this `WorkTime` and after a time duration (can't be predicted because It's a decision) The company manager take a decision to switch to another WorkTime, So HR employee executes the decision by inserting a specific start date and inserts roughly end date, So the next activation may conflict with the most recent one.**
11. What's the actual business meaning of a WorkTime activation/deact?

    **During the year, The employees whom subject to a specific `WorkTimeRegulation`, Their `WorkTimes` changed based on `the activation`, I mean The `WorkTime` may be 8hours from Oct to Dec then switched to 6 hours(another `WorkTime`) from Jan to Sep and so on It's like a cycle.**

> Note: The decision provides for start date only (e.g Winter `WorkTime` Starts from date ...)
>   and not specifying the end date! So it is inserted roughly and as a
>   result the start date for the next activation may conflict with the
>   end date for the previous one)

12. Is it because they might create activations ahead of time? In that
    case it's the same thing IMO. Enforcing the end date of a
    conflicting activation to be exactly when the primary activation
    starts is pretty much the same as having a deFacto concept, because
    when you use deFacto to force an activation over another that
    overlaps you implicitly state that the other activation has ended
    when the deFacto one starts, no?

    **After asking the business expert about this, he explained the case like this: The HR department sends a suggestion for the activation period (Start date, expected end date) to the company manager, After the manager confirmed the suggestion, The HR executes the suggestion, and they need an alert before the end date of the current active `worktime` to notify them to send the next suggestion to the company manager so that they can use `defacto` to enforce the next period or just activate not overlapped `worktime`, So yes the activations made a head of time**

13.I think the only thing we need to work out is whether multiple
    activate suggestions can be made in parallel and what are the rules?

**No multiple activate suggestions can be made in parallel for the same `WorkTimeRegulation`, It may be for multiple `WorkTimeRegulation` but not for the same `WorkTimeRegulation`.**

14. Furthermore, does the suggestion approval process need to be modeled
        in the system (e.g. tracking who approved, perhaps by uploading an
        email copy of the approval)?

    **No this process is performed manually, no need to model it.**
15. Finally, should you only be able to activate a suggested activation
    that was approved?

    **YES**

Comment: Could you just explain the business problem this solves and what invariants must be protected instead of the database structure.

Comment: @plalx I have updated the question, Could U take a look please?

Comment: What behaviors can be performed on `WorkTime`? So far I can see it can be activated. In order to validate the activation do you need the entire activation history or only the latest event? Does the activation rules span multiple `WorkTime` (e.g. if one is active then the other can't be)? Can the `name`, `numberOfHours`, etc of activations be modified? Should modifying these details conflict with other business operations (e.g. activating a `WorkTime`? To find ARs you look at behaviors and invariants. Whatever data is needed to check an invariant must be part of the same AR.

Comment: That's the general rule, but although we might want strong consistency everywhere and protect invariants at all times, it's not always possible and we have to bend the model and rules to make the system usable most likely due to collaboration (concurrency requirements).

Comment: @plalx, I have updated my question, Could You take a look please

Comment: "if there was conflict between two activations of the same WorktimeRegulation" Could you expand on what kind of conflicts could occur? Shouldn't the system prevent activation conflicts from occuring? How does the activation process work exactly? Also, what would be the cost of having `WorktimeRegulation` point to a non-existing `WorkTime` for a short period of time (e.g. `regulation.activateWorkTime(workTimeId)` but then the activated work item gets deleted)? Can `WorkTime` get deleted/archived? Can `WorkTime` be associated to a different `Regulation` after it's creation?

Comment: Also, are you sure it doesn't matter if for instance, `name` or `numberOfHours` changes at the same time as someone attempts to activate a `WorkTime`? What I'm trying to figure out with these questions is whether `Regulation` needs a collection or `WorkTime` entities or `WorkTime` can be it's own aggregate, where the activation state is maintained on `Regulation`.

Comment: @plalx  I have updated my question, Could You take a look please

Comment: Last question. I'm still not clear as to why conflicting activations could occur. Why would you want to allow overlapping activation periods, but then use a flag to specific which one to enforce. Seems easy enough to prevent overlapping activation periods instead, no? Is it really possible from the business perspective that two activation periods overlap conceptually? Why do users even enter the `startDate` and `endDate` manually? Couldn't you just track the dates at which activation/deactivation occurs in the system? What's the actual business meaning of a `WorkTime` activation/deact?

Comment: @plalx I have updated my question, Could You take a look please

Comment: Let's say there's a current `Activation` of work time `W1` for period `[2018-01-01, null]`. When a different work time `W2` gets activated, why wouldn't the end date of `W1` activation simply gets updated to the start date of `W2`, effectively eliminating all potential period overlapping?

Comment: Is it because they might create activations ahead of time? In that case it's the same thing IMO. Enforcing the end date of a conflicting activation to be exactly when the primary activation starts is pretty much the same as having a `deFacto` concept, because when you use `deFacto` to force an activation over another that overlaps you implicitly state that the other activation has ended when the `deFacto` one starts, no?

Comment: @plalx : I have updated my question and added a new suggestion (Two aggregates the `WorkTime` is the child in both of them)

Comment: What about having an expected period and an actual period? They would suggest an activation providing an expected period, but the actual period would only update according to true activation events without overlaps.

Comment: @plalx this’s okay with me

Comment: I think the only thing we need to work out is whether multiple activate suggestions can be made in parallel and what are the rules? Furthermore, does the suggestion approval process need to be modeled in the system (e.g. tracking who approved, perhaps by uploading an email copy of the approval)? Finally, should you only be able to activate a suggested activation that was approved?

Comment: So far I think you'd be good by just having a `WorktimeRegulation` AR with `WorkTime` entities. The history of activations wouldn't be modeled within the `WorktimeRegulation` boundary however. You could probably track the history simply with domain events, such as `ActivationSuggested`, `ActivationEnabled`, etc. Within `WorktimeRegulation` you would only have to track the current suggestion and currently enabled activation to enforce rules such as "no more than one enabled activation at a time".

Comment: Code may look like `activationHistoryEntry = regulation.suggestActivation(workTimeId, expectedPeriod); save(activationHistoryEntry); save(regulation);`. If you have a standard domain event store with a projection mechanism you wouldn't need to model history entries as immutable aggregates.

Comment: @plalx I will be grateful if you post an answer with more details please

Comment: Could you answer the above questions first?

Comment: @plalx I have updated my question, Could you take a look please

Comment: @plalx could you help me please

Comment: Hopefully my answer will help. It's certainly not perfect as it's hard to grasp all the intricacies of the domain through such a simple text discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following rules:

- There can only be one active work time per work time regulation at any given time.
- There can only be one pending work time activation suggestion at any given time.
- The suggestion approval process doesn't have to be tracked in the system.
- A work time regulation can't point to a non-existing work time. A work time can't be deleted or archived once it's been activated once.

I think it would be reasonable to model this so that `WorkTimeRegulation` is an aggregate root that has a collection of `WorkTime` entities. Furthermore, it would have to model the current activation suggestion as well as the current active `WorkTime` in order to enforce the above-mentioned rules. The suggestion/active state could either be modeled on the `WorkTimeRegulation` itself or the `WorkTime` instances (in which case the root must ensure only one is active at a time, etc.). That's really a design preference at that point and both strategies would allow you to protect the invariants. Furthermore, the `WorkTime` entity should also track whether or not it was ever activated in order to prevent further modifications to it's other attributes (e.g. `numberOfHours`).

Here's a draft of what it may look like:

[image]

The above model would ensure all required data to check invariants are part of the same root and models the minimum structure required to store the state and enforce the rules in memory.

However, this model alone doesn't solve the activation history problem. You dont need the entire history to enforce the invariants, so you dont need to model it within the boundary of an AR, but the business will certainly still need such data.

At this point there are several strategies you could use, like:

- Model your ARs with event sourcing, getting history for free.
- Dispatch domain events in parallel to storing the current AR state and store them in an event store, still allowing you to project the history of events.
- Model an immutable `ActivationHistoryEntry` AR. E.g. `historyEntry = regulation.activate(workTimeId); save(historyEntry); save(regulation);`. This is very similar to domain events.

The above model is certainly not perfect and could be refined. For instance, I also thought of modeling the concept of an `Activation` VO rather than using a boolean flag, which could be of different types (active, inactive, suggested). This would perhaps allow for a more expressive language, where for instance an `ActiveActivation` can only be obtained through the activation of an `ActivationSuggestion`, where the `ActiveActivation` holds onto the suggested end date (if available, to notify HR they need to send the next suggestion).

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason I'd like your input on this model and if you'd have different ideas when event sourcing or domain events are not used, but the history still need to be kept somehow.

Comment: @Anynamedonotcare Any questions?

Comment: Firstly I want to thank u so much for your effort, really I'm so grateful for u.

I have set of questions, I hope u could help me :
1- I see the same behaviors (methods) in both the root and the aggregate, Could u illustrate the difference?
2- Your model exclude the `activation concept` and replace it with states in `WorkTime` Could explain more what should I do if I want to keep the `activation` as a concept, Is this more suitable in my case or your suggested model?

Comment: 3-You asked me a lot of very useful questions in the core business, and some of those I never thought about before, Could I ask How could I improve my skills to distill the model and identify the aggregates ?

4- This question is not so related to my question, But I wonder How the `DDD` solve the m-m relationship ?

5-I feel the `DDD` is confusing and not easy at all, How to learn it ?

Comment: 1. If we follow the tell don't ask principle and preserve encapsulation we don't ask the root for a sub-entity and then apply a command on it. We ask the root to apply a command to a sub-entity and the root works out the details. This also makes sure that the root is notified of all state modifications. For instance, in `regulation.activate(workTimeId)` the root would make sure any previously activated `WorkTime` gets deactivated first and then call `targetWorkTime.activate()` which in turn would check if there was an ongoing suggestion for this `WorkTime` (suggestion needed prior activation)

Comment: 2. I haven't deemed useful to model the activation explicitly as it seemed to me it was more needed for historical purposes (querying needs) which can be derived from stored domain events or `ActivationHistoryEntry`s (if chosen over events). However like I said perhaps modeling an `Activation` as a VO or even an entity within `WorkTime` could be useful. You'd have to explore this further.

Comment: 3. For every use case that must be performed. Ask yourself what state it operates on and which data does it need to access to protect invariants. This would help to identify your transactional boundaries (ARs). Once you have a general idea then check if the size of your AR is practical and where concurrency conflicts could occur and how often they would (e.g. how often parallel use cases would target the same AR). If the size causes a huge memory overhead or if there would be too many concurrency conflicts try to check if you can further break apart the AR.

Comment: In some scenarios you may want to revisit invariants with the business experts to see if they are true invariants or a consistency delay (ms, secs, hours, etc.) could be acceptable instead of strong consistency. For example, imagine a blog system where only 1000 posts per thread are accepted. You may be tempted to hold a collection of `Post` within `Thread`, but you'd have concurrency conflicts then and `Thread` may take lots of memory to load. In that case perhaps the rule can be loosened or the process adapted through eventual consistency.

Comment: E.g. you create the Post no matter what but it gets removed if later on it is detected that it was > 1000. Perhaps the 1000 rule is also enforced at the UI level (e.g SELECT TOP 1000) so that even if 1001 made it no one sees it, etc.

Comment: 4. You often don't have to model two-way relationships. You'd model the side of the relationship that makes the most sense and rely on a DB query to express the other side. For instance, a `Question` may have many `Tag` and a `Tag` can have many `Question`. Perhaps you can just hold a collection of `Tag` in `Question` and if you want to know how many `Question` per tags you do a DB query. If the `Question` can have thousands of tags perhaps you model a `QuestionTagging` AR instead of the collection. E.g. `tagging = question.addTag(someTagId); save(tagging);`.

Comment: The model couldn't then perform set validation to avoid duplicate tags, but perhaps you put a unique constraint in the DB for that or you detect it in an eventual consistent way and remove the duplicate, etc.

Comment: 5. The Implementing Domain-Driven Design book by Vaughn Vernon is a good place to start IMO.

Comment: Thank u so much  I’m so grateful

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong in the second option. Worktime doesn't belong to first aggregate as a child entity. It just belongs to the second aggregate as the root. The first aggregate would reference the second aggregate. You said you don't want it because it would break the integrity. Well it's all about where you want to put transactional boundaries. If you want to change the three entities in one transaction, go for the first opinion (one aggregate). If you can live with delays, go for the second option (two aggregates) with eventual consistency between them.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like you have a wrong idea about aggregates. Your new drawing:

```
WorktimeRegulation(ROOT)      |      WorkTimeActivation(ROOT)
    |                         |             |
    V                         |             V
WorkTime                      |         WorkTime
```

Is wrong too. If WorkTime is a child entity in an aggregate, then the other aggregate must reference the root, not the child. And apart from that, WorkTime is one entity. You cannot draw it two times belonging to both aggregates. An entity just belongs to one aggregate.

You have 3 entities. You have these posibilities of aggregates:

- One aggregate with the 3 entities.
- Two aggregates: one with 2 entities; and another one with the other entity.
- Three aggregates: each one with one entity.

Some basic rules:

- If an aggregate references another, it must reference the root, invoking the behaviour that the root offers.
- Consequently, a child entity of an aggregate cannot be referenced by an entity of another aggregate.
- A child entity of an aggregate can reference another aggregate root.

What you must study is whether in a transaction you have to modify the state of the 3 entities in order to maintain the invariants the same, or you can take out one entity apart that would be another aggregate on its own.

Even if the 3 entities should form just one aggregate to keep invariants the same... you could split it too, but you would have to communicate both aggregates with events in order to have eventual consistency, as you broke transactional consistency.

Comment: Why can't use one entity in two aggregate as a root in one of them and as a child in the other one !

Comment: Because one entity is just one entity. it cannot be in two places at the same time. You cannot have an aggregate inside another. If an entity is a child entity in one aggregate, it can reference the root entity of another aggregate, but not being itself the root (it would be an aggregate nested into another). Aggregates are not nested, they define transactional boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

> Should one root be for the whole aggregate graph or should multiple roots be in the same graph?

It depends.

The more important point: it depends very little on the structure of the relationships between domain entities.

Identifying aggregate boundaries is primarily about how the state of the entities change; an in particular if any of those changes require *simultaneous* coordination between the two entities.

Grouping entities together into a single aggregate makes change coordination simple, but there is a cost - you can no longer make independent concurrent changes to the entities.  Independent edits will either need to block waiting for each other, or one edit will need to be recalculated.

Splitting entities into separate aggregates makes concurrent editing much easier, but at a cost - coordinating changes among entities becomes harder.

A single aggregate really wants to have a single storage location -- trying to coordinate writes at two different locations (aka two phase commit) is a drag.  If two entities belong to different aggregates, the model implies that they could be stored in separate appliances.

It also suggests that they have independent life cycles -- one of the advantages of aggregates is having a clear understanding of the graph of objects that get archived together.

Another thing to check is whether your object graph is multiple entities, or a single record with a compound value describing its state.  If it might be a single value, then that suggests trying a single aggregate first.

You might also look at the source of the data -- especially sources for changes over time.  If the changes always come from the same authorities, then it is a lot more likely to be a single aggregate.  On the other hand, if `WorktimeRegulation` and `Worktime` data comes from different sources, that makes concurrent change more likely, which hints at multiple aggregates.

An important question to explore: what's the cost to the business if the entities aren't in exact agreement?  If the data stored in Worktime doesn't agree with WorktimeRegulation for a minute, does anybody notice?  Cases where you have some freedom to make things line up, where you have flexibility about the order in which changes are made, tend toward multiple aggregates.

> Two aggregates the WorkTime is the child in both of them

Every entity in your model should belong to exactly one aggregate; you could, in theory have a WorkTime inside a WorktimeRegulation, and a WorkTime inside a WorktimeActivation, but to have the *same* worktime be inside a WorktimeRegulation aggregate *and* inside a WorktimeActivation aggregate is "against the rules".  It implies that either that changes to WorktimeActivation can influence WorktimeRegulation or that WorkTime itself is something that should be broken into two separate pieces.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I can't understand many points in your answer, because it includes many abstract ideas, the concrete examples are so much better in this case, Could you provide a concrete example to apply these conditions on so that I could understand all these ideas and apply it on my case please.

Comment: I have updated my question and added a new suggestion (Two aggregates the `WorkTime` is the child in both of them)